# App Tracking Transparency message doesnt show in some devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have implemented App Tracking Transparency in the project for 14.x devices. Most of the devices the ATT alert message is displayed to user like this [image]

**But in iPhone8 with OS 14.4, ATT message never displayed at all**. Has anyone experienced this issue?

Appreciate any help on this. Thank you

Comment: I have definitely seen on some of my devices that the ATT dialog is never shown; you just get `.denied`.  I am not sure why. It seemed to be related to devices that had 14.3. I have one device that went straight from 14.2 to 14.4 and it doesn't have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there are some issues with iOS 14.4 and 14.5 which block App Tracking on the system level and don't allow the user to change this setting. Most probably, you faced with the same issue. To check it, just open:
Preferences -> Privacy -> Tracking. If you turned off "Allow Apps to Request to Track", just enable it. If it's grayed-out and you can't enable it, you can wait for an iOS update or install an iOS beta version with the hope it'll be fixed for your devices.

The same happened for me, but in my case, I used an iOS 14.5 Beta, so when I rolled out to iOS 14.4 Stable, it worked for me again.

The sample of a blocked tracking option:

[image]